Sending Drone Object Location via XBee with Raspberry Pi and GPS
I’m working on a project where I have a drone that have a Raspberry Pi equipped with a camera, GPS and XBee modules. right now I’m making the drone get the location of an object when it recognize one with opencv.
i want to know if i can send that location to a robot through xbee for it to go and collect the object, and how if it’s possible.
Any additional insights or tips on any other part of the project is very helpful.
thanks in advance.
Note : I already connected 2 xbee with XCTU but i still don't know how to make them send the location.

Once an object is recognized, you need to extract its coordinates from the image.you need to establish communication between the Raspberry Pi (on the drone) and the robot. You can do this by configuring one XBee module as the transmitter and the other as the receiver.Once an object is recognized and  location is determined, you need to format this location data into a message that can be transmitted via XBee. This can be as simple as a string containing the coordinates, or you can use a structured format like JSON. You then send this message using the XBee module connected to the Raspberry Pi.
